# How to apply style to a label element dynamically in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5 and am trying to apply a few styles to the label element. Below is the piece of the code in the controller.

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    var busFunId = this.getView().byId("busFun");
    jQuery.sap.byId(busFunId.getId()).parent().css("width", "20%");
},
```

Below is the line of code for the label element in view.xml.

```
<Label text="Business Function" id="busFun"/>
```

Here, label element is rendered within a **div** with default css classes. I am trying to adjust the width by applying on the **div** element, the parent of the label element.

This is not taking effect. Please share a solution if anyone have faced the same.

**Rendered HTML:**

> ```
> <div class=""><label id="busFun" />sample</label></div>
> ```

**Expected HTML:**

> ```
> <div class="" style="width:20%"><label id="busFun" />sample</label></div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to adjust the width, don't add styling, but make use of the property `width`. (check [sap.m.Label](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Label) for more properties you can use).

```
<Label text="Business Function" width="20%"/>
```

If the properties aren't sufficient for your styling, you can make use of css-class(es) to style your Label.

```
<Label class="custom" text="Business Function" width="20%"/>
```

If you decide to make use of css, don't forget to include a `fileName.css` file to your project and 
 to register the file in your `manifest.json` as a resource.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few options:

Apply via JS with addStyleClass:

```
   this.getView().byId('yourControlId').addStyleClass("cssYouLoaded");
```

Load the css file via manifest:

```
"resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "content/css/style.css"
                }
            ]
        }
```

And apply on your element:

```
<Label text="Business Function" id="busFun" class="style"/>
```

If you area defining the css file, don't forge the !important. A lot of times the sapui5 Css overwrite your custom ones.

```
.imagemCabecalho {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0.4em !important;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 8em;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.. Geraldo. I have added a few additional info to the original question. I am aiming to apply a css class to the container div which has the label element.

Comment: Can you paste the parent control of the label? One possible solution is to use the html namespace. Example:  `<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" 
 xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" 
 xmlns:forms="sap.ui.layout.form" 
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
 <forms:SimpleForm maxContainerCols="1" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" editable="true">
  <l:VerticalLayout id ="layout">

   <html:div>

    <label>....    <label>
   </html:div>


  </l:VerticalLayout>
 </forms:SimpleForm>
</core:FragmentDefinition>`